# Where is the percentile function in CRAN -R

Tags: r

I do not understand all the terminology inside R. I have only 100 level statistics, trying to learn more.

I am guessing R has a built-in percentile function named something I don't recognize or know how to search for.

I can write my own, but rather use the built in one for obvious reasons.

Here's the one I wrote:

```
percentile <- function(x) return((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))
```

Comment: if you want to make this into a utility function for general use you might consider adding `na.rm=TRUE` to your `min` and `max` calls so that the function works sensibly when there are `NA`s in the data

Comment: Percentiles (or `quantiles` in R) are actually something different from what you describe in your question.  You are describing a scaling problem.  Of the four answers at the moment, only the answer by @BenBolker answers your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are looking to find out specific percentiles from a data set, take a look at the `quantile` function: `?quantile`.  By multiplying by 100, you get percentiles.

If you are looking into converting numbers to their percentiles, take a look at `rank`, though you will need to determine how to address ties.  You can simply rescale from rank to quantile by dividing by the length of the vector.

Comment: I tried the quantile function before I asked my question. It's not quite what I was looking for. Your suggestion to look the rank function was very helpful. Because I can just do rank(x) / length(x), which gives the same result as my percentile function. Neat!

Comment: @freewary I'm glad you found a shorter way of describing your problem.  But be very careful.  There may be some special cases where `rank(x)/length(x)` gives the same result as your original question, but these will be exceptions and your results will be different depending on your data.

Comment: @Andrie is correct - do take come care.  Ranking is nuanced as are quantiles.  If there are ties or NAs, there could be some surprises.

Comment: @Iterator I have problems with the ties and i do not know how to address them? What would be the best approach?

Comment: @user1007742, a data.table call that worked for me is: dt[ , percentile_x := rank(x, na.last = "keep", ties.method = "average")/
               sum(!is.na(x)), ]

Answer (score 9):

You can do this via

```
scale(x,center=min(x,na.rm=TRUE),scale=diff(range(x,na.rm=TRUE)))
```

but I'm not sure there is actually a built-in function that does the scaling you're asking for.

Comment: +1 For realizing the OP isn't asking about percentiles, but scaling.

Comment: That kind of answer is why I am starting to love R. That's not really what I'm looking for, but it illustrates that R encourages so many ways to approach any question.

Answer (score 6):

The `quantile` function might be what you are looking for.  If you have vector `x` and you want to know the 25th, 43rd, and 72nd percentiles you would execute this:

```
quantile(x, c(.25, .43, .72));
```

The semicolon is, of course, optional.

See http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/numerical-measures/percentile

Comment: This might work for me: quantile(women$height,(1:length(women$height))/length(women$height)). Your explanation helped me understand the function. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can search for functions (or for just about anything else) via `RSiteSearch` e.g.,

```
RSiteSearch("percentile")
```

Answer (score 0):

On the off chance you are thinking about a percentile based on a distribution, here is a different answer.  Each probability distribution has a set of 4 functions associated with it: a density, distribution, quantile, and generating function.  These are prefixes of d-, p-, q-, and r-, respectively (with the same suffix based on the distribution).  You have a uniform distribution, and are asking about percentiles (distribution) so you want `punif`. It takes `min` and `max` as two of its arguments.

Comment: > punif(women$height,1,length(women$height))
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
not sure how to make this work. More tips please.

Comment: To do this I think you would want `punif(women$height,min(women$height),max(women$height))` (or `with(women,punif(height,min(height),max(height)))`

Answer (score 0):

I made this function function, check it. Data is any vector, row of any matrix o data frame.

```
percentiles<-function(Data) return(quantile(Data, seq(0,1, by=.01)))
```